# Shortening CSS selectors separated with a comma with SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have this CSS rule in a stylesheet:

```
#breadcrumbs, #breadcrumbs span {
    font-size: 0.750rem;
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to avoid repeating `#breadcrumbs` with SASS. One of the way to achieve this would be:

```
#breadcrumbs {
    font-size: 0.750rem;
    span {
        font-size: 0.750rem;
    }
}
```

This, however is even worse as I have to repeat `font-size: 0.750rem`.

What is the way to actually **shorten** the CSS from above with SASS?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One possible option could be [referencing the parent](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector) by using the ampersand `&`:

```css
#breadcrumbs {
    &, & span {
        font-size: 0.750rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The SASS should be

```
#breadcrumbs 
    &, & span 
        font-size: 0.750rem
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
#breadcrumbs {
    &, span {
        font-size: 0.750rem;
    }
}
```

Note that repeating the parent selector `&, & span` is not necessary and is equivalent to just `&, span` because the parent context is already there provided by nesting. The comma separates the child selectors so the SCSS is actually equivalent to this:

```
#breadcrumbs {
    & {
        font-size: 0.750rem;
    }
    span {
        font-size: 0.750rem;
    }
}
```

Note that there's the opposite situation when you would like to apply styles to the current selector `&` *and* other, *not nested* selectors. You would then need the `@at-root` directive. (Not to say that this is especially good practice, maybe mixins might work better for this.) Example:

```
[type="text"],
[type="number"],
[type="password"],
select {
  font-size: 0.9em;

  @at-root &, [type='checkbox'] {
      margin: .5em 0;
  }
}
```